# Create a PreStop container lifecycle hook using a Helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a pod that needs to clean up an external reference when it is terminated.  (I can do this with a a curl command.)

I looked into [container lifecycle events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) and they seem just what I need.

But the example shows creating a Pod resource directly via yaml.  With Helm, I just made deployments and the pods are auto created.

How can I define a PreStop container lifecycle hook in a Kubernetes deployment?

Answer (score 2):

I should have looked a bit longer.

The [Writing a Deployment Spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#writing-a-deployment-spec) section of the deployment documentation says:

> The .spec.template is a Pod template. It has exactly the same schema as a Pod, except it is nested and does not have an apiVersion or kind.

So I can just add my hook in there as if it were the Pod yaml.